# Flutter: Storing language and theme preference when using GetX utility functions

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

Is there any way to store user preferences (and retrieve them on reboot) when using **GetX**'s utility functions:

```
Get.changeTheme(ThemeData().dark)
```

as well as

```
Get.updateLocale(Locale('en', 'US'));
```

So far I am only able to change both, the theme and the language, but I have not found a way in GetX to **persevere any of my changes to any sort of storage** in order to be loaded when reopening the app the next time. Is there anything I am overlooking? Is there any way to hook into the startup process and check for some stored values (e.g. in `SharedPreferences`) and pass them to my `locale` and `theme` properties in `GetMaterialApp`?

This is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      translations: Messages(),
      locale: Get.locale,
      theme: Get.theme,
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            TextButton(
                onPressed: () => {
                      Get.changeTheme(
                          Get.isDarkMode ? ThemeData.light() : ThemeData.dark())
                    },
                child: Text('change_theme'.tr)),
            TextButton(
                onPressed: () => {
                      Get.updateLocale(Get.locale == Locale('en', 'US')
                          ? Locale('de', 'DE')
                          : Locale('en', 'US'))
                    },
                child: Text('change_language'.tr)),
          ],
        ));
  }
}

class Messages extends Translations {
  @override
  Map<String, Map<String, String>> get keys => {
        'en_US': {
          'change_theme': 'Change Theme',
          'change_language': 'Change Language',
        },
        'de_DE': {
          'change_theme': 'Farbschema wechseln',
          'change_language': 'Sprache wechseln',
        }
      };
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is easier to do with [GetStorage](https://pub.dev/packages/get_storage).

If you're just changing from light to dark theme, it's a matter of storing a simple bool every time the theme is changed.

Here's one way to do this with a basic settings class.

```
class SettingsController extends GetxController {
  ThemeData themeData;

  final box = GetStorage();

  @override // called when you use Get.put before running app
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    _restoreTheme();
  }

  void _restoreTheme() {
    bool isDark = box.read('isDark') ?? true; // null check for first time running this
    if (isDark) {
      themeData = ThemeData.dark();
    } else {
      themeData = ThemeData.light();
    }
  }

  void storeThemeSetting(bool isDark) {
    box.write('isDark', isDark);
  }
}
```

The `themeData` variable from the `SettingsController` class gets initialized depending on the bool value from storage. And that `themeData` file is what you pass into your `GetMaterialApp`, which looks like this.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controller = Get.find<SettingsController>();
    return GetMaterialApp(
      theme: controller.themeData,
      title: 'Material App',
      home: StorageDemo(),
    );
  }
}
```

Then put both of these lines in your Main method before running your app.

```
  await GetStorage.init();

  Get.put(SettingsController());
```

Here's a demo page where you can test this.

```
class StorageDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controller = Get.find<SettingsController>();
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Get.changeTheme(ThemeData.dark());
                controller.storeThemeSetting(true);
              },
              child: Text('Dark Theme'),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Get.changeTheme(ThemeData.light());
                controller.storeThemeSetting(false);
              },
              child: Text('Light Theme'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you have a more complex `ThemeData` file, then the same concept applies but you have to store each color individually, which I find is easiest to do by storing the `int` value of a color.

```
  int colorValue = Colors.red.value; // store this int
```

Then when restoring from storage you can use this function

```
Color mapIntToColor(int value) {
    return Color(value);
  }
```

As for your language settings, same thing. Just add a `Locale` variable to your Getx class, store a couple strings, initialize before running the app, then pass that `Locale` variable into the locale field in `GetMaterialApp`.

Answer (score -1):

It should be possible using SharedPreferences. Assign key value pairs (e.g. theme, dark) or (theme, light) that you can save and read and then run your logic on those to call the ThemeData when opening the app.

saving:

```
_saveTheme() async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final key = 'theme';
  final value = _theme;
  prefs.setString(key, value);
 }
```

reading when initializing app and set theme - something like this (I did not test):

```
_readTheme(context) async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final key = 'theme';
  final _theme = prefs.getString(key) ?? "light"; //set theme to light if the key is not found in SharedPreferences
  Get.changeTheme(
   _theme == 'light' ? ThemeData.light() : ThemeData.dark())
}
```

Comment: Ok, could you provide some code example using the code I posted above to illustrate how you would "*call the ThemeData when opening the app*"?

Comment: I edited my answer to show what I would do in your case - you will need to experiment a bit and fine tune where needed